# Duration of the busy cursor when launching a Windows desktop application

Tags: winapi, launch, mouse-cursor, user32

When you launch a Windows desktop application, the system changes the arrow to one with an animated busy spinner (presumably from [IDI_ARROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadcursorw) to [IDI_APPSTARTING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadcursorw)).  Once the application presents a window, the cursor is restored to indicate that it's ready for input.

With my own Win32 applications, the spinner continues for several (5?) seconds, even though the main window is fully rendered and ready for interaction.  It was my understanding that the spinner vanishes once the just-launched program started pumping messages.  More specifically, I thought it used the same criteria as [WaitForInputIdle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-waitforinputidle).

Since Windows 10, however, some applications, including ones I've written, appear to be stuck with the busy cursor for the duration of the timeout—even beyond the moment that the application becomes responsive to mouse and keyboard input.

**What should I do in my programs to let the system know that initialization is complete and the spinner is no longer needed?**

**UPDATE**: The problem occurs only when launching the application from the keyboard (like a CMD prompt, the Run window, or using the keyboard to launch the process in the debugger in Visual Studio).  If you double-click the program with the mouse, the spinner vanishes quickly, as expected.

**UPDATE 2**:  Given that others cannot repro, my best guess is that there's a buggy driver involved. Thanks to everyone who helped brainstorm in the comments.

Self-contained repro below.

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT OnPaint(HWND hwnd, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    ::BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    RECT rc;
    ::GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    ::DrawTextW(ps.hdc, L"Hello, World", -1, &rc,
                DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_NOPREFIX);
    ::EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
}

LRESULT MyWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_DESTROY: ::PostQuitMessage(0); break;
        case WM_PAINT:   return OnPaint(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
    return ::DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int nShowCmd) {
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = MyWindowProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hinst;
    wc.hIcon = NULL;
    wc.hCursor = ::LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = ::GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW);
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"My Very Own Window Class";
    const ATOM atomClass = ::RegisterClassW(&wc);
    if (atomClass == 0) return ::GetLastError();

    // Ugly cast for WinAPI's legacy type punning.
    const LPCWSTR wndclass =
        reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(static_cast<UINT_PTR>(atomClass));

    const HWND hwnd =
        ::CreateWindowW(wndclass, L"Test", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL,
                        NULL, hinst, nullptr);
    if (hwnd == NULL) return ::GetLastError();

    ::ShowWindow(hwnd, nShowCmd);

    MSG msg = {0};
    while (::GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
        ::DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return (msg.message == WM_QUIT) ? static_cast<int>(msg.wParam) : 1;
}
```

Comment: The busy mouse is shown as long as the window's message queue is not empty (aka the window is idle). I've ran your code on my Windows 10 x64 box, but it's very hard to see the busy mouse as it's so brief and sometimes not visible at all, so there's clearly no timeout. If I add say a Sleep(5000) after the first call to DispatchMessageW, I do see the busy mouse during 5 seconds. It may be specific to your machine/environment.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but on a side note: You an get rid of your "Ugly cast for WinAPI's legacy type punning" by using `wc.lpszClassName` instead of `atomClass` when calling `CreateWindowW()`

Comment: @Simon Mourier:  That's what I expected, but that's not what's happening for me.  On my Windows 10 x64 box, the mouse cursor shows busy for a full 5 seconds.  In fact, there's time launch my test app, click the close button, and watch the window vanish _before_ the spinner goes away.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  Yeah, but why bother making Windows hash the class name twice? ;-)

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy "*that's not what's happening for me*" - that would imply that your message queue never goes idle. Have you tried logging the messages that `MyWindowProc()` actually receives? Is there ever a gap within that 5-second period where nothing gets logged? Maybe on your system, there are internal system/timer messages being generated that are keeping the message queue more active than you are expecting.

Comment: If you want to spare the system from hashing the class name twice, then there's [`MAKEINTATOM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-makeintatom).

Comment: @Remy Lebeau:  I logged the windows messages.  WM_PAINT happens within the first 50 ms, followed by about 1100 ms of nothing but a WM_NCHITEST-WM_SETCURSOR-WM_MOUSEMOVE-loop.  More than I expected, given that my hand isn't even on the mouse.  However, there are no messages after that, yet the cursor continues to spin.

Comment: A clue!  The problem occurs only when launching the application **from the keyboard** (CMD prompt, Run, or the debugger).  If I double-click the program icon in an Explorer window, the spinner vanishes almost instantly (as @Simon Mourier described).

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy - I tried that too, including other shell such as Windows Terminal, but they all behave the same :-)

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do in my programs to let the system know that initialization is complete and the spinner is no longer needed?

There seems to be agreement that the spinner should vanish once the application has started pumping messages and has no pending input events queue.

The fact that's not working in all cases for me is likely a local issue, like a buggy driver spamming the input queue (which somehow never make it to window messages).  There's not much point in hashing that out here on SO, so I'm putting up this community wiki answer and moving on.